Wildfly 9 realm to Wildfly 28 jdbc-realm database authentication
I need help converting a Wildfly 9 Realm to Wildfly 28 realm.
The original is the following:
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
    <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="forrashazRealm">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/forrasDS"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from v_active_user where username=?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select group_name as userRoles,'Roles' from user_join_group where user_name=?"/>
                            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="anonymousUser"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>

    </security-domains>
</subsystem>

How can I make it to elytron 17.0?
Thank you very much!

I found a migration guide at Wildfly documentation.
